# executing sql files in for loop, error is not recorded and not stoping after error

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, sqlcmd

in below batch script, I expect all scripts were kept at c:\temp and they will execute one by one and reord all successful/error records in log file, if any error occours then it should stop 
what syntex going wrong here, one more I kept this batch script and all sql scripts in one folder only

```
@Echo Off
FOR /f %%i IN ('DIR C:\temp\*.Sql /B') do call :RunScript %%i
GOTO :END

:RunScript
Echo Executing %1
@set SName=someservername
@set DbName=somedbname
@set path=C:\temp

echo sqlcmd -S %SName% -d %DbName% -i %1 -o "%path%\log.txt" 
if not %errorlevel%==0 exit
Echo Completed %1

:END
```

Comment: Why do you have `echo` before `sqlcmd`? Remove it!

Comment: ok, still I have got same problem

Comment: Just remembered: when you `@set path=C:\temp` you cause shell not to find `sqlcmd.exe`, unless it exists in current directory or in `c:\temp`!

Answer (score 0):

You need goto :eof at end of subroutine (after "Echo Completed %1"); otherwise you are not returning from called subroutine.  Your code also assumes no spaces in filenames.  Is that the case?

Comment: That's not correct. Reaching end of batch file is same as `GOTO :EOF`.

Comment: That's assuming that the OP has shown ALL of the code.  It is still preferrable to add the GOTO :eof in case more code is added later.

Comment: I would do that also. However, `:END` means much!

Comment: still log file is getting blank

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I will point errors first, solution after. I don't know `sqlcmd`, but I'm checking [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx).

```
FOR /f %%i IN ('DIR C:\temp\*.Sql /B') do call :RunScript %%i
```

May be a problem if filenames have spaces within

```
@set path=C:\temp
```

As already told, avoid using system variables. SQLCMD may rely on %path%!

```
echo sqlcmd -S %SName% -d %DbName% -i %1 -o "%path%\log.txt"
```

`echo` cause command line to be displayed, not executed!
From documentation, `-o`parameter implies "A file of the same name from a prior sqlcmd session will be overwritten". So, each time you run `sqlcmd`, previous log is overwritten.

```
if not %errorlevel%==0 exit
```

Use `exit /b` or command line interpreter is stopped, which may break flow when using nested batches.

My suggestion:

```
FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %%i IN ('DIR C:\temp\*.Sql /B') do call :RunScript "%%i"
GOTO :EOF

:RunScript
Echo Executing %1
SQLCMD -S someservername -d somedbname -i %1 -b -m-1 1>> "C:\temp\log.txt"
IF %ERRORLEVEL%==0 EXIT /B
Echo Completed %1
```

EDIT: typo correction

EDIT: correcting switches: `-o` stands for output. Better use `-m` and catch `stdout`.

Comment: This script is much improved is doing good but log.txt created as blank, I expect result in it

Comment: I have 5-10 commnads and log file is getting blank, I can't understand commands are executed or not ?

Comment: You MUST read documentation. `-o` stores output. And this should only be SQL queries results.

Comment: LS_dev, I was done as per your mofdified script, still getting same error, log file is generated but it is blank

Answer (score 0):

for %%G in (*.sql) do (sqlcmd /S %sqlhost% /d %sqldbname% -E -b -i "%%G" >> output.txt if ERRORLEVEL 1 exit)

Above code will loop through all the *.sql in a folder. If error encountered in any of the script , error will get logged in the output.txt file and it will stop the batch process immediately.Create a batch file with the above two lines of code and put it in your folder(C:\temp)